Unable to Inspect Flutter HTTPS traffic using JMeter
Apache JMeter Version: v5.6.3
App type: Flutter
I'm in the process of creating performance script for a flutter mobile app (.apk). But the respective network traffic is not recording with the JMeter. But other than app, rest of the network traffic of the connected mobile device has been recorded without any issues.
Steps followed:

Installed latest Root_CA certificate to Mobile device.
Connected to same Wi-Fi network.
JMeter Https script recorder configured with 8889 Port.
Manual Proxy enabled in mobile device with Laptop ip and 8889 port.
Strat recording.

The build I used is not a Debug build. Do we need a build with any special configurations in order to intercept Network traffic of Flutter apps via JMeter?

It's not "flutter", it's Android network security configuration
You need to amend your application manifest in order to allow trusting user-installed certificates

In the application tag of your app manifest add the next line:
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"


Create network_security_config.xml file under your application resources directory and put the following code there:

Build your application in debug mode

Replace the original .apk on the device with the newly built one


More information:

Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording
and Configuring an Android device to work with Burp Suite

